# pysqlite for python 3.3.5 on Centos 6.5

Tags: python, centos6, sqlite, easy-install

I have compiled `python 3.3.5` from source in the `/opt` folder as follows:

```
yum install sqlite-devel
./configure --prefix=/opt/python3
make
make install
ln -s /opt/python3/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3
```

I then installed easy install as follows:

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-3.3.tar.gz
tar xvf setuptools-3.3.tar.gz
cd setuptools-3.3
cat ez_setup.py | /opt/python3/bin/python3.3
```

Finally I did:

```
cat ez_setup.py | /opt/python3/bin/py
/opt/python3/bin/easy_install sphinx
/opt/python3/bin/easy_install pysqlite
```

Which gives me:

```
  File "setup.py", line 85
    print "Is sphinx installed? If not, try 'sudo easy_install sphinx'."
```

I have also tried compiling `pysqlite` from source which gives me the same error.

Sphinx binaries are in `/opt/python3/bin/sphinx-*`

I have tried copying them to `/usr/bin` with no luck.

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: Is `/opt/python3/bin` at the head of your `$PATH`?

Comment: @MadHatter added /opt/python3/bin to path with the same result